# Within my for loop it appears that it is ignoring if statements

Tags: java, if-statement, applet, for-loop, repaint

I'm pretty new at java and I've been trying to write a method that draws a gradient from one configurable color to another. However, it appears that if statements inside of the for loop are being ignored.

How can I fix this? or is there something else I'm missing?

and usage of the method is:

Gradient.dVertical(Graphics,Top left corner X,Top left corner Y,Size X,Size Y,tarting Red Value,Starting Green Value,Starting Blue Value,Ending Red Value,Ending Green Value,Ending Blue Value);

***EDIT: I figured out what the real problem was and I fixed it. When it should have been incremental down it was going up. So I added a couple more if statements and that cleared it up. <strike>Using random integers when calling the method did reveal another problem though. With certain values it will not finish drawing and it will just cut off in the middle.</strike> FIXED***

Here's the fixed part of the code if anyone is interested

```
if (rrepeat == true)
        {
            //prevents division by zero
            if(rrate!=0)
            {

                //for a rate that must repeat checks
                //whether or not it is time to increment
                check = k%rrate;
                if (check==0)
                {
                    if(ered<sred)
                    {
                        rr--;
                    }
                    if(sred<ered)
                    {
                        rr++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    rr = rr;
                }
            }       
        }
```

Comment: No one is going to read the whole code that you posted. Edit it to show the part that is of importance or relevance to the question.

Comment: Did you `repaint` the canvas?

Comment: Could you clarify on which statements are not being executed?

Comment: When you say it appears they're being ignored, what are you actually seeing happen?

Comment: reason I posted all of it is because im not completely sure what the problem is.
@manmir the whole applet window appears white

Comment: @timster it appears that all of statements in the for loop are not executed not entirely sure though

Comment: Your first problem to solve is finding out where is the error located and what's causing it. Consider either using a debugger or peppering your code with println statements so you know the state of your variables at various locations in your code and know what code is executed and what isn't.

Comment: To make this simpler and a better question, I suggest you do the following: 1. Try a single color gradient (remove green and blue, change red only). 2. Show the code that calls repaint(), update(Graphics), and dVertical(...). 3. Tell exactly what you see

Comment: Can we try to be a bit more welcoming to new members of our community?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be overriding the `paint` method.

Here's an example: [Introduction to applets](http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/java106/java106.html)